# Checking an order is for only today

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I realize this is a relatively basic quesiton, however datetimes always screw me up and I want to make sure I'm doing this properly (this audit will be getting promoted to the bossman). Using sql server 2008 r2. Some sudo code below for what I want

I should mention transactionDate is currently a datetime. does that change things?

```
DELCARE 
    @today datetime,
    @tomorrow datetime

SET @today = --CODE TO GET THE DATE FOR TODAY
SET @tomorrow = --CODE TO GET THE DATE FOR TOMORROW

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE custID = '788'
    AND status = 'Cancelled'
    AND transactionDate --IS ONLY TODAY AND NOT TOMORROW OR ANY DAY AFTER
```

Comment: What kind of data do you have in the transactionDate column?

Comment: datetime. edited my post to reflect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with dates, then you should use the `date` data type.  Here is a version of your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE custID = '788'
    AND status = 'Cancelled'
    AND cast(transactionDate as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```

You can also write this as:

```
select *
from table
where custId = '788' and status = 'Cancelled' and
      TransactionDate >= cast(getdate() as date) and
      TransactionDate < cast(getdate() + 1 as date)
```

I thought the cast prevented the index from being used, but Aaron has enlightened me otherwise in the comments.  [Here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server.aspx) is a more extensive explanation of sarability in SQL Server.

Comment: Why do you want tomorrow to match? Also I'd be careful with +1 shorthand... it is not valid in a lot of cases in 2008+.

Comment: I should mention transactionDate is currently a datetime. does that change things?

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . I misread the condition.  I really thought it said essentially "today or tomorrow but not any day after".

Comment: Here is why I prefer the ANSI standards when there are no other real differences: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2008/03/20/which-to-use-or.aspx

Comment: Oh, and no, this is the one exception where casting the column does *not* preclude the use of an index. It is not intuitive that this is the only case (at least that I know of), but your first query (like mine) is fully sargable.

Answer (score 7):

If `transactionDate` is `DATETIME`, then:

```
AND CONVERT(DATE, TransactionDate) = CONVERT(DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

If `transactionDate` is `DATE`, then:

```
AND transactionDate = CONVERT(DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Both of these will still use an index on `transactionDate`, but this is a special case. Usually the first form will destroy sargability.

Comment: I should mention transactionDate is currently a datetime. does that change things?

Comment: @mhopkins321 nope. Did you try it? And if it is storing just a date (or you only care about the date part) have you considered using `DATE` instead?

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . If you won't reference it, I will.  There is a detailed blog post on date/datetime comparisons in SQL Server at https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, just replace the GETDATE() with your input DATE

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE custID = '788'
    AND status = 'Cancelled'
    AND DATEDIFF(DD,GETDATE(),transactionDate)=0
```

Comment: I should mention transactionDate is currently a datetime. does that change things?

Comment: Just note that most functions against the column render it non-sargable - meaning a potential seek will have to become a scan. This often makes performance terrible. Also lazy shorthand like `DD` is dangerous. For example, guess what `DATEPART(Y, GETDATE());` returns? If you guessed 3 or 13 or 2013, you'd be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a couple of ways to do this, as others have posted.

The best way would be to simply set

```
where transactionDate = @toDay
```

This approach will work if the transactionDate only contains the DATE part (no hours or minutes, so at midnight) and then the @toDay is the same, just for GETDATE() or similar.

As ljh writes you can also do a DATEDIFF on day, but that will be extensive as it will do the DATEDIFF on every row - not very efficient.

You can however check between dates, so something like this.

```
WHERE transactionDate >= '2013-03-22' and transactionDate < '2013-03-23'
--Substitute the chars for variables
```

This will give you all the rows where transactionDate is occurring between midnight and, well next midnight.

edit: I just saw that Gordon answered the same thing, and included that part about indices being usable, which I forgot to add.

edit: As Aaron pointed out, between isn't a good thing. It's been a while since I actually wrote any non-adhoc sql so I tend to forget stuff like this :(

Comment: Oh no, [please please please don't use BETWEEN for date/range queries](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx).

Comment: Oops, a bit too fast on the keyboard there.